# Keyboard not showing up in Webview

Tags: android, flutter, webview

How to solve the Keyboard not showing up when the input field on the web is being clicked. I am currently using webview_flutter

Comment: Check this:https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25436

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding to your XML:

```
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Comment: I have tried this, but still no keyboard showing up